# BeautifulSoup Scraping - 'find' method does not return any children in 'div' tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract information from [http://financials.morningstar.com/company-profile/c.action?t=AAPL][1]

 Especially, the 'CIK' field from the 'Operation Details' section as shown in the [image][1] 
 This is the code I have used:

 
 ```page = requests.get('http://financials.morningstar.com/company-profile/c.action?t=AAPL')``` 

```soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5lib')```
 ```div = soup.find(name='div',attrs={'id':'OperationDetails'}) ```

 
 Upon ```print(div)``` I get an empty tag output. 
 
 However, upon inspecting the page the 'div' tag with **id='OperationDetails'** does have child tags under it. Am I missing something here?
 
 I am a beginner in using BeautifulSoup and I was practicing on this website. What is wrong and how do I now get the 'table' element that has the information (CIK) I am looking for? 
 
 Sincere thanks. 
 edit: I am really sorry, I dont know why Stackoverflow is removing image and website links after the question is posted. Please let me know if you need any additional details, I will be prompt in responding as quickly as I can. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Operation Details" panel is loaded from external URL. You can use this example how to load it:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = (
    "http://financials.morningstar.com/cmpind/company-profile/component.action"
)

query = {
    "component": "OperationDetails",
    "t": "XNAS:AAPL",  # <--- change to your ID
    "region": "usa",
    "culture": "en-US",
    "cur": "",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=query).content, "html.parser")

cik = (
    soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "th" and "CIK" in tag.text)
    .find_next("td")
    .text
)
print(cik)
```

Prints:

```
320193
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej. How can I know if such a page has dependencies from an external URL?

Comment: @TheEqualizer Inspect the source code, for example `print(soup)` - if you don't see the value there, most probably the value is loaded from external source (you can see all external sources in Developer Tools -> Network Tab)

Comment: Thank you very much Andrej. I sincerely appreciate your quick response. This helps a lot.